# C# function nested within a class method

Tags: c#, function, methods, nested

I'm trying to implement a function within a Class method and I am somewhat new to C#.

Basically, I have a method that iterates through row in a database and sets values to variables. Then, if a document has been created already it updates the document, if not it creates the document. I'm trying to factor out some of the code and I don't know where to put it as it still needs a reference to my variables. I would like to factor out the repeated items in the if else statement.

```
    private void SyncKinases()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = gn.ExecuteQuery("dx.kinasedatasheet.selectstagingkinases", null);

        TreeProvider tp = new TreeProvider(ui);
        VersionManager vm = new VersionManager(tp);
        TreeNode node;

        WorkflowManager wm = new WorkflowManager(tp);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                string className = "dx.kinasedatasheet";
                string title = dr["Title"].ToString();
                string technologyPlatform = dr["TechnologyPlatform"].ToString();
                string ambitGeneSymbol = dr["AmbitGeneSymbol"].ToString();
                string targetDescription = dr["TargetDescription"].ToString();
                string entrezGeneSymbol = dr["EntrezGeneSymbol"].ToString();
                int entrezGeneID = int.Parse(dr["EntrezGeneID"].ToString());
                string aliases = dr["Aliases"].ToString();
                string kinaseGroup = dr["KinaseGroup"].ToString();
                string species = dr["Species"].ToString();
                string accessionNumber = dr["AccessionNumber"].ToString();
                string kinaseConstruct = dr["KinaseConstruct"].ToString();
                string kinaseForm = dr["KinaseForm"].ToString();
                string expressionSystem = dr["ExpressionSystem"].ToString();
                double avgZValue = 0;
                if (!(dr["AverageZValue"] is DBNull))
                {
                    avgZValue = double.Parse(dr["AverageZValue"].ToString());
                }
                string panel = dr["Panel"].ToString();
                string compoundsKds = dr["CompoundsKds"].ToString();
                string mutationRelevance = dr["MutationRelevance"].ToString();
                string mutationReferences = dr["MutationReferences"].ToString();

                string kinaseAliasPath = "/Kinase-Data-Sheets";

                if (!(dr["NodeID"] is System.DBNull))
                {
                    node = tp.SelectSingleNode(int.Parse(dr["NodeID"].ToString()));
                    vm.CheckOut(node);
                    node.DocumentName = ambitGeneSymbol;
                    node.NodeName = ambitGeneSymbol;
                    node.SetValue("Title", title);
                    node.SetValue("TechnologyPlatform", technologyPlatform);
                    node.SetValue("AmbitGeneSymbol", ambitGeneSymbol);
                    node.SetValue("TargetDescription", targetDescription);
                    node.SetValue("EntrezGeneSymbol", entrezGeneSymbol);
                    node.SetValue("EntrezGeneID", entrezGeneID);
                    node.SetValue("Aliases", aliases);
                    node.SetValue("KinaseGroup", kinaseGroup);
                    node.SetValue("Species", species);
                    node.SetValue("AccessionNumber", accessionNumber);
                    node.SetValue("KinaseConstruct", kinaseConstruct);
                    node.SetValue("KinaseForm", kinaseForm);
                    node.SetValue("ExpressionSystem", expressionSystem);
                    if (!(dr["AverageZValue"] is DBNull))
                    {
                        node.SetValue("AverageZValue", avgZValue);
                    }
                    node.SetValue("Panel", panel);
                    node.SetValue("CompoundsKds", compoundsKds);
                    node.SetValue("MutationRelevance", mutationRelevance);
                    node.SetValue("MutationReferences", mutationReferences);
                    node.SetValue("DocumentPublishTo", null);

                    node.Update();
                    updatedKinaseCount++;
                    vm.CheckIn(node, null, null);
                    WorkflowInfo wi = wm.GetNodeWorkflow(node);
                    if (node.IsPublished)
                    {
                        wm.AutomaticallyPublish(node, wi, null);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    node = TreeNode.New(className, tp);
                    node.DocumentName = ambitGeneSymbol;
                    node.NodeName = ambitGeneSymbol;
                    node.SetValue("Title", title);
                    node.SetValue("TechnologyPlatform", technologyPlatform);
                    node.SetValue("AmbitGeneSymbol", ambitGeneSymbol);
                    node.SetValue("TargetDescription", targetDescription);
                    node.SetValue("EntrezGeneSymbol", entrezGeneSymbol);
                    node.SetValue("EntrezGeneID", entrezGeneID);
                    node.SetValue("Aliases", aliases);
                    node.SetValue("KinaseGroup", kinaseGroup);
                    node.SetValue("Species", species);
                    node.SetValue("AccessionNumber", accessionNumber);
                    node.SetValue("KinaseConstruct", kinaseConstruct);
                    node.SetValue("KinaseForm", kinaseForm);
                    node.SetValue("ExpressionSystem", expressionSystem);
                    if (!(dr["AverageZValue"] is DBNull))
                    {
                        node.SetValue("AverageZValue", avgZValue);
                    }
                    node.SetValue("Panel", panel);
                    node.SetValue("CompoundsKds", compoundsKds);
                    node.SetValue("MutationRelevance", mutationRelevance);
                    node.SetValue("MutationReferences", mutationReferences);
                    node.SetValue("DocumentPublishTo", null);
                    node.SetValue("DocumentCulture", "en-US");

                    TreeNode parentNode = tp.SelectSingleNode("DiscoveRx", kinaseAliasPath, "en-US");
                    node.Insert(parentNode);
                    //vm.CheckIn(node, null, null);
                    newKinaseCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        ArchiveItems(archivedKinaseCount, "dx.kinasedatasheet.selectarchivekinases");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just refactor your code so you don't need to set the node values in different cases:

```
private void SyncKinases()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = gn.ExecuteQuery("dx.kinasedatasheet.selectstagingkinases", null);

    TreeProvider tp = new TreeProvider(ui);
    VersionManager vm = new VersionManager(tp);
    TreeNode node;

    WorkflowManager wm = new WorkflowManager(tp);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string className = "dx.kinasedatasheet";
            string title = dr["Title"].ToString();
            string technologyPlatform = dr["TechnologyPlatform"].ToString();
            string ambitGeneSymbol = dr["AmbitGeneSymbol"].ToString();
            string targetDescription = dr["TargetDescription"].ToString();
            string entrezGeneSymbol = dr["EntrezGeneSymbol"].ToString();
            int entrezGeneID = int.Parse(dr["EntrezGeneID"].ToString());
            string aliases = dr["Aliases"].ToString();
            string kinaseGroup = dr["KinaseGroup"].ToString();
            string species = dr["Species"].ToString();
            string accessionNumber = dr["AccessionNumber"].ToString();
            string kinaseConstruct = dr["KinaseConstruct"].ToString();
            string kinaseForm = dr["KinaseForm"].ToString();
            string expressionSystem = dr["ExpressionSystem"].ToString();
            double avgZValue = 0;
            if (!(dr["AverageZValue"] is DBNull))
            {
                avgZValue = double.Parse(dr["AverageZValue"].ToString());
            }
            string panel = dr["Panel"].ToString();
            string compoundsKds = dr["CompoundsKds"].ToString();
            string mutationRelevance = dr["MutationRelevance"].ToString();
            string mutationReferences = dr["MutationReferences"].ToString();

            string kinaseAliasPath = "/Kinase-Data-Sheets";

            bool isNewNode = false;
            if (!(dr["NodeID"] is System.DBNull))
            {
                node = tp.SelectSingleNode(int.Parse(dr["NodeID"].ToString()));
                vm.CheckOut(node);

            }
            else
            {
                node = TreeNode.New(className, tp);
                node.SetValue("DocumentCulture", "en-US");
                isNewNewNode = true;
            }

            node.DocumentName = ambitGeneSymbol;
            node.NodeName = ambitGeneSymbol;
            node.SetValue("Title", title);
            node.SetValue("TechnologyPlatform", technologyPlatform);
            node.SetValue("AmbitGeneSymbol", ambitGeneSymbol);
            node.SetValue("TargetDescription", targetDescription);
            node.SetValue("EntrezGeneSymbol", entrezGeneSymbol);
            node.SetValue("EntrezGeneID", entrezGeneID);
            node.SetValue("Aliases", aliases);
            node.SetValue("KinaseGroup", kinaseGroup);
            node.SetValue("Species", species);
            node.SetValue("AccessionNumber", accessionNumber);
            node.SetValue("KinaseConstruct", kinaseConstruct);
            node.SetValue("KinaseForm", kinaseForm);
            node.SetValue("ExpressionSystem", expressionSystem);
            if (!(dr["AverageZValue"] is DBNull))
            {
                node.SetValue("AverageZValue", avgZValue);
            }
            node.SetValue("Panel", panel);
            node.SetValue("CompoundsKds", compoundsKds);
            node.SetValue("MutationRelevance", mutationRelevance);
            node.SetValue("MutationReferences", mutationReferences);
            node.SetValue("DocumentPublishTo", null);

            if (isNewNode)
            {
                TreeNode parentNode = tp.SelectSingleNode("DiscoveRx", kinaseAliasPath, "en-US");
                node.Insert(parentNode);
                //vm.CheckIn(node, null, null);
                newKinaseCount++;

            }
            else
            {
                node.Update();
                updatedKinaseCount++;
                vm.CheckIn(node, null, null);
                WorkflowInfo wi = wm.GetNodeWorkflow(node);
                if (node.IsPublished)
                {
                    wm.AutomaticallyPublish(node, wi, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ArchiveItems(archivedKinaseCount, "dx.kinasedatasheet.selectarchivekinases");
}
```

You now also don't need all of those temporary variables from `dr` columns since they will only be used once.  Removing those will make your method much shorter and more readable.

Comment: So you mean I could do: node.SetValue("Title", dr["Title"].ToString();)?

Comment: This is great. I wasn't event thinking about it like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to refactoring your routine I'd recommend creating some extension methods to save you some typing.  For example, here's the an extension for parsing your doubles:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static double ToDoubleIfNotDBNull(this object item)
    {
       if (item is DBNULL) return 0;
       return double.Parse(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

So then your code becomes:

```
double avgZValue = dr["AverageZValue"].ToDoubleIfNotDBNull();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new method and send the values as parameters.

```
void SetNodeValues(Node node, DataRow row)
{
    string title = dr["Title"].ToString();                
    ....

    node.SetValue("Title", title);
    ...
}
```

You might be able to do it all with a for loop (untested and not match your variables)

```
foreach(var col in Table.Columns)
    node.SetValue(col.Name, dr[col]);
```

If you were using an ORM, you could send an object instead of the DataRow but that is beyond the scope of this question.